# Helicopter torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

When torque is removed via the engine, what force makes the helicopter spin in the same direction as the rotors? I.e the opposite of torque reaction. What aerodynamic force would this be?

Answer (score 1):

There's two options:

Firstly, the tail rotor. The primary use for this is yaw control, including correcting for torque from the main rotor, so if this is still running it will over-correct and cause the rotation you're talking about.

Secondly, friction. In a situation where the helicopter is autorotating (behaving like an autogyro), if the gearbox is still engaged there is a lot of mechanical drag which will cause torque. The energy source for this is airflow, so the aircraft needs horizontal and/or vertical airspeed.

Comment: What about in the case of a hovering autorotation at say five feet. And Zero airspeed it takes all of the right pedal I have not to let that helicopter spin left. The engine will also be disengaged from the rotor

Comment: In that case it's going to be the existing angular momentum of the main rotor being shed to the body of the aircraft via mechanical friction.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines but if the helicopter has a moving swashplate, how would that momentum get transferred to the fuselage to make the helicopter spin?

Comment: The tail rotor can be replaced with a second main rotor, either offset horizontally (back to front or side to side), or vertically. Sikorsky makes designs that do each of these.   And then there's this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOTAR

Comment: @Wes Friction of the bearing between the main rotor and the airframe. It's not much but it is there will transfer momentum from the rotor to the airframe and drag the airframe along with it.